# flutter pull_to_refresh_flutter3 Set pull-down background color

Tags: flutter

flutter  pull_to_refresh_flutter3  Set pull-down background color??
seek help!!!!

[image]

Comment: What is the question you'd like to ask my friend?
老铁，侬问啥子哟？

Comment: Can you include your current snippet that will reproduce the same issue ?

Comment: And it depend on what header you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the `SmartRefresher` with a widget to provide color, and then wrap the child with another widget to change the color. You might find better way like using theme but it depends on header type.

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: SmartRefresher(
    enablePullDown: true,
    controller: _refreshController,
    enablePullUp: true,
    header: ClassicHeader(),
    onRefresh: () async {},
    child: Material(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (c, i) =>
```